# UFT does not recognize objects - sometime

Tags: automated-tests, qtp, hp-uft

I have the problem, that I have a testcase with static values.
But when I test the application ( e.g. ) on the first try it was successful, but after restarting the test, some objects are not recognized by UFT. And the next 5 runs run without problems.

This is not depending on any object, this happens on different objects in different runs.

The testcase start the application by itselfe, so there should be no side effects by an old instance or another program.

Here are some examples, how I access the Objects.

Via the Object Repository :

```
if Control.WinObject("ThunderRT6UserControlDC").VbWindow("frmAddress").ActiveX("FarPoint fpCombo 3.0 Control").Exist(2) then
Control.WinObject("ThunderRT6UserControlDC").VbWindow("frmAddress").ActiveX("FarPoint fpCombo 3.0 Control").Click
end if
```

Via Description :

```
Dim oDesc 
Set oDesc = Description.Create 
oDesc("text").value= Name
Control.VbButton(oDesc).Click
```

Both result in an error that tells me, the object is not available.

Comment: Have you properly ensured that although the test starts the application, it correctly logs out/closes/terminates the session afterward?

Comment: yes I did. And it is so strange that is sometimes works and sometimes not

Comment: Do you by any chance open the app before you open UFT, that would be a factor. Are you using any virtual relations ?

Comment: Can you be more specific? Is it web app or desktop? Which technology?

Comment: What kind of "wait for" strategy do you employee to make sure that they object is available to be interacted with?

Comment: @PrageethSaravanan - I have restarted the server the app is on a few times, so no other app ( exept the uft IDE is running )

Comment: @olyv its a normal application ( VB6 & Dotnet ) I test active x and normal windows controlls with it .

Comment: @dmcgill50 I check befor accessing the object if it exists ( wait 3 seconds ) - the object is there.
I use the object reposetory or descriptive programming. both with the same result sadly

Comment: @Twiebie Can you give an example of with some code and the exact error message that you receive?

Comment: @dmcgill50 I have added some samples to the original post.

Comment: Can you describe how you get the object called Control?  Is it possible that somehow that isn't getting set right during the failed run?

Comment: @TrimbleEpic what do you mean by 'how I get the control' ? 
e.g. the control with from the object repo. During the fail I started the object spy on the control, that was not available. But UFT recognized it as the one which already is in the object repo.

Comment: I mean: in your code snippet, you show "if Control.WinObject("Thund..."  ... so the WinObject is a member of Control...   I checked to see if Control was a global object within UTF, and couldn't find it, so I guessed that Control is an object variable that you've created and populated with a test object from the Object Repository... I was going to guess that maybe somehow during the failed test runs that the object variable named Control isn't getting properly populated, and thus references to the WinObject member could fail....   I was just guessing.

Comment: @TrimbleEpic yes this call is within a function and Control is a parameter. 
Control = vbWindow("Application").vbWindow("Subwindow") . 
The problem is, this are only examples. it's like UFT changes it's behavior on every run, because when an error comes up ( 1 of 20 runs ) it's everytime another object, which is not identified.